# Training a classifier with the last fold

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn. Does the following code train the classifier with the last fold? Or does it leave the classifier untrained?

```
scores = [clf.fit(data[train], Y[train]).score(data[hpc_test], Y[hpc_test]) for train, hpc_test in kfold]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after this expression `clf` is trained on the last fold. `fit` stores the model it learns in the estimator it is called on.